# Jquery validating a specific form on a page with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, selector

Some suggestions or advice please. 
I'm trying to validate a multi-form page but I'm not sure how to specify the form in jquery selector:

```
<form id="form_a">
    <label>First Name</name><input type="text" class="required"><br>
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" class="required">
<button onclick="validate('form_a')">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form_b">
    <label>Serial No </name><input type="text" class="required"><br>
    <label>Brand </label><input type="text" class="required">
<button onclick="validate('form_b')">Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form_c">
    <label>First Name</name><input type="text" class="required"><br>
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" class="required">
<button onclick="validate('form_c')">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function validate(whichform) {

    $(whichform+" .required").each(function(i){
        if ($(this).val().indexOf() < 0){
        alert("null value detected")
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red")
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your caase you are passing the id to the method, but you are not using the id selector, also you will have to return false from the event handler if you want to prevent the submission of the form

```
<button onclick="return validate('form_c')">Submit</button>
```

so

```
function validate(whichform) {
    var valid = true;
    // whichform is the id so use id selector here
    $('#' + whichform + " .required").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            alert("null value detected")
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid red")
            valid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css("border", "")
        }
    });
    //return the valid state
    return valid;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JhV8p/)

---

But a more jQuerish solution will be is to use jQuery event handlers like

```
<form id="form_a">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" />
    <br/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var valid = true;
        // whichform is the id so use id selector here
        $(this).find(".required").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                alert("null value detected")
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid red")
                valid = false;
            } else {
                $(this).css("border", "")
            }
        });
        //return the valid state
        return valid;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WLT53/)

Comment: strange with the first one. I'm able to get inside validate function with an alert() test but then I'm not getting inside
$('#' + whichform + " .required").each(
I have an alert() test inside this function but alert() test isn't isn't triggering. I don't think it likes this selector. I'm trying to replicate your jsfiddle and see what's the problem...

Comment: @Quaking-Mess sorry I didn't get you... what do you mean

Comment: @Quaking-Mess can you confirm whether the attached fiddle sample is working

Comment: sorry I've fixed it. I forgot to add class="required" to my input fields. It's working fine now! Thank you Arun. You're very thorough :)

Comment: @Quaking-Mess I would recommend using the second method

Comment: there is a problem. Even if there is text. It still alerts "null value detected". Is this if statement correct? $(this).val().indexOf() < 0

Comment: @Quaking-Mess it should be  `$(this).val().length == 0`

Comment: Yeah that was my fault sorry. Thanks works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().children('.required').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val().indexOf() < 0){
                alert("null value detected");
                $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And remove the `onclick=""` from your html. As a [best practice](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-html-best-practices-for-beginners--net-4957), try to avoid inline Javascript. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmww3/)

Comment: This is interesting. I think this is the best method. Just let JQuery do all the searching for elements. No need to identify forms and id's I would have gone with this too as it's the shortest method.